# Why the function is executing statements even after return statement is executed?

Tags: java, recursion

I checked with debugging also it is going to statement =>if(sum==1) return true; but then also it is executing further statements.

```
static long solve(int l, int r){
    // Your code goes here
    long sum=0;
    boolean t=0;
    for (int i=l;i<=r;i++) {
        t=beautiful(i);
        if (t==true) {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

static boolean beautiful(int num) {
    if (num<=0) return false;
    if (num==1) return true;
    int sum=0;
    while (num>0) {
        int rem=num%10;
        sum=sum+rem*rem;
        num=num/10;
    }
    if (sum==1) {
        System.out.print("some");
        return true;
    }
    System.out.print("one");
    beautiful(sum);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's because `beautiful` is calling itself recursively

Comment: I've edited your code fix the layout and indentation. You have the option to revert the edit if you prefer your code to be unreadable.

Comment: Try replacing the last two lines of method `beautiful` with this line: `return beautiful(sum);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After then you call *beautiful* method, it goes into it and gets the result and continues. So you can do this despite you call *beautiful* method and return false;

```
return beautiful(sum);
```